# $\int_0^1 e^{2x}dx - |\int_0^1 e^x \overline{\phi(x)}|^2= \int_0^1|e^x - \int_0^1 e^t \overline{\phi(t)}dt\phi(x)|^2dx$ in $L_2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Prove in $L_2[0,1]$ that $\int_0^1 e^{2x}dx - |\int_0^1 e^x \overline{\phi(x)}|^2= \int_0^1|e^x - \int_0^1 e^t \overline{\phi(t)}dt\phi(x)|^2dx$ where $\int_0^1 |\phi(x)|^2=1$

denote $f=e^x$ so this can be rewritten as $$\langle f , \overline{f} \rangle - |\langle f,\phi \rangle |^2 = \parallel f - \langle f, \phi \rangle \phi \parallel_2^2$$

How can I finish the proof from here? tried opening RHS though didn't amount to significant progress.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a square on the left-hand side of your identity. In fact, let's start from the right-hand side. First of all, we denote by $$
a:=\int_0^1 e^x\overline{\phi}(x)dx.
$$
Thus, the right-hand side can be rewritten as: $$
\quad \quad \quad \mathrm{RHS}=\int_0^1e^{2x}dx-\overline{a}\int_0^1 e^x\overline{\phi}(x)dx-a\int e^x\phi(x)dx+\vert a\vert^2\int \vert\phi\vert^2(x)dx. \quad \quad \quad (*)
$$
Now notice that, by using the definition of $a$ we have: $$
-\overline{a}\int_0^1 e^x\overline{\phi}(x)dx-a\int e^x\phi(x)dx=-2\vert a\vert^2.
$$
Hence, replacing into $(*)$ and recalling that $\Vert \phi\Vert_{L^2}=1,$ we obtain $$
\mathrm{RHS}=\int_0^1e^{2x}dx-\vert a\vert^2=\int_0^1e^{2x}dx-\left\vert \int_0^1e^x\overline{\phi}(x)dx\right\vert^2,
$$
which is exactly the latter identity you wrote on your post (exactly the left-hand side of it, which is not exactly the same as the one on the title).

Comment: Thanks! and yes, I was missing that square in the title.. edited now.